# How to avoid OSErrors when attempting to write to a file used by another program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Whenever I write to the files, sometimes python would error when the file is being read by a other program.
The common error I would get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lavacat1\Desktop\ROBLOXStream\Converter.py", line 14, in <module>
    pixf = open("data.json", "w")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'data.json'
```

Full code: This maybe very unoptimised as it seems to me but I got no other way to make that different

```
WIDTH1 = 256
HEIGHT1 = 144
import time
import pyautogui
from PIL import Image
import re
while 1<2:     
    time.sleep(0.05) 
    im = Image.open("output.jpg", "r")  
    width, height = im.size 
    pix_val = list(im.getdata())    
    line = re.sub('[()]', '', str(pix_val)) 
    lineo = re.sub('[ ]', '', str(line))    
    pixf = open("data.json", "w")   
    sizef = open("size.json", "w")  
    sizer = open("size1.json", "w") 
    e = pixf.write(lineo)   
    s = sizef.write(str(width)) 
    p = sizer.write(str(height))    
    pixf.close()    
    sizef.close()   
    sizer.close()
    myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    myScreenshot.save("output.jpg")
    im = Image.open("output.jpg")
    new_image = im.resize((WIDTH1, HEIGHT1))
    new_image.save('output.jpg')
    print("s")
```

Additional notes: This is my first project, its streaming related as it takes a screenshot of my whole screen and converts it to a RGB table every 50 miliseconds, but due to the conversion and screenshotting it may be longer then that.

Version: Python 3.8.6

Comment: Python did not find your file. Are you sure it is in the same folder as your script?

Comment: Yes it is in the same folder as my script, except when its accessed by a other program python fails to write to it and closes the *script*

Comment: Then you should (for "the other program") update the path to the `json` you want to access. Furthermore, remember that, to access and modify any file within a python script, you need the file to not be being accessed by other programs - so remember to close the connection with `file.close()`.

Comment: I have already added file.close in my script a while ago, however i cannot prevent the program from accessing the JSON file

Comment: Could you also post your folders structure?

Comment: The structure of the folder is very complicated. Converter.py (main script), data.json (file thats being used by the other program), size.json (width for the image), size1.json (height for the image), output.jpg (The screenshot that is then resized to a specific size). Those are all the files involved in the python script

Comment: When you access `data.json` from the other script, are you closing it? And you want to append or write a new file every time? Maybe you should use `w+` as argument, to create and write, or `a+` to create and append.

Comment: Consider using `try`/`except` to handle when the error occurs. You can either retry the operation, do some alternative (if there is one), return an error code, or exit gracefully.

Comment: This is Windows, I assume? (UNIX-y operating systems let multiple programs have the same file open for write at the same time unless you go out of your way to do otherwise).

Comment: There is some confusion here. If this were a sharing error, `open` would raise `PermissionError`. Instead you show an `EINVAL` (22) error, which the C runtime uses for any Windows error code that doesn't have an explicit mapping to a POSIX error code. Secondly, Python, and most Windows programs that use the C runtime, by default opens files with read and write access sharing, so files can be opened any number of times without a problem. The access that's not shared commonly is delete (and rename/move) access.

Comment: The script is ran in windows 7. I will try to use the `try` method

Comment: I fixed the script, thanks for the support!